# How to set up conditional jq transform?

Tags: json, conditional-statements, jq

I need to transform a JSON, which can either have 1 value or 2. So it can be:

```
{"form":{"textinput1":"aaa"},"params":{"context":""}}
```

or

```
{"form":{"textinput1":"aaa"},"params":{"context": "something"}}
```

---

And the output I need is this:

```
{"input": {"text": "aaa"}}
```

or

```
{"input": {"text": "aaa"},"context": "something"}}
```

---

JQ Transform would be:

```
{"input": {"text": .form.textinput1}}
```

or

```
{"input": {"text": .form.textinput1},"context":.params.context}
```

---

But how to merge these two into a condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jq has two basic conditionals: `if ... then ... else ... end` and `A // B`.  In your case, the first suffices:

```
{"input": {"text": .form.textinput1}}
+ (.params.context | if . == "" then null else {"context":.} end)
```

If you need to apply some transformation, say f, to `.context` if it is not “”, then replace the final `.` by `f`.

Comment: I need to return to this issue. Actually my "context" is a JSON object, not a string. So I need to add |fromjson to make it work: {"input": {"text": .form.textinput1},"context":.params.context|fromjson}. Unfortunately in first case (context is empty), this crashes. What can I do?

Comment: Unfortunately the details you've given so far about the new question are insufficient to offer a detailed answer. However, I am puzzled that you think it's necessary to convert the object to a string. Anyway, if you cannot figure it out, then I'd suggest opening a new SO question.

Comment: Thank you for your input so far. I have edited the original post with requirements adding that |fromjson. When I don't convert the object to string, then \ characters are being added to each " and API doesn't like it.

Comment: I think it crashes here: + (.params.context|fromjson    - trying to perform |fromjson when "context":"". Perhaps you know a workaround?

Comment: :tojson is even worse, it creates things like this -  \\\":\\\"

Comment: really, |fromjson works very good, when "context":JSONobject. When it "context":"" it crashes with this message: jq: error (at /tmp/AG_JQe4tqyQ:0): Expected JSON value (while parsing '')

Comment: Changing the question as you have is not fair to those who have provided valid answers and tends to make the thread difficult for others to follow. Since you seem to be new to SO, I have updated my answer, but in future please avoid changing the Q once there is a valid A. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, I am new to SO and I don't want to be unfair. It is entirely my fault, that I changed requirements. Please advise what I should do to make things right. (Still, it would be great if you could help me on this, I think we are extremely close)

Comment: As I said, it would have been better to accept a valid answer and then start a new Q.  As it is, the Q now fails the mcve test - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - so please fix it one way or the other.

Comment: Done. I have reverted to "string" version. Perhaps you know the solution to my problem, anyway?

Comment: Tx. I do not know what the new problem is.  Have you read the mcve article?

Comment: Ok, your last comment was the solution that worked: "if you need to apply some transformation, say f, to .context if it is not “”, then replace the final . by f." Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

**jq** solution:

```
jq '.params.context as $ctx 
    | {input: {text:.form.textinput1}} 
    + (if ($ctx | length) > 0 then {context:$ctx} else {} end)' file.json
```

---

- `.params.context as $ctx` - assign `.params.context` value into variable `$ctx`
- `if ($ctx | length) > 0` - check if `$ctx` is not empty